# Why modn and modular exponent g^x mod n are not cryptographic hash functions?

Tags: hash, rsa, signature

I have been trying to find a solution to this question and wasn't able. 
When it comes to signatures and Hash Functions, how would be possible to show that $\pmod n$ and modular exponent $g^x \pmod n$ are not cryptographic hash functions?

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: What do you know about pre-image attack, collision attack and forgeries?

Comment: I know the basics and still researching and learning about hashes, this is a very new topic for me.

Comment: Hint 1 ) consider the message is $m>n$ can you find a pre-image? collision?

Comment: Actually, if $n$ is a hard-to-factor number, and $g$ generates a sufficiently large subgroup, then $g^x \pmod n$ *is* collision resistant (and hence preimage and second preimage resistant as well); you'll need to exclude that case from your demonstration...

Answer (score 1):

A function is called a cryptographical hashing function if it satisfies 3 properties:

- not invertible
- the codomain must be large enough (>160 bits so that the number of cases to find a collision is $2^{80}$)
- strong resistant collision.
  Mod function does not satisfy the third one. So we can find 2 different values x1=2 and x2=n+2 and have the same hashing value,
  so x1 mod n = x2 mod n.
  Also for the other function, $g^x$ mod n is very similar.